# Slicing a SparseVector to get a SparseVector in Scalala

Tags: scala, scalala

I'd like to slice a sparse vector in [scalala](http://www.scalanlp.org/docs/scalala/0.4.1-SNAPSHOT/#package) and get another sparse vector.  A normal slice always gives a standard vector.  Can I provide an implicit function for doing this while slicing and if so what would it look like?

As an example, I'd like to accomplish the following:

```
val v:SparseVectorRow[Double] = ...
val v2:SparseVectorRow[Double] = v(List(1,3,5))
```

Lastly, I'm using Scalala release 1.0.0.RC3-SNAPSHOT.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define your own appropriately parametrized [`CanSliceVector`](http://www.scalanlp.org/docs/scalala/0.4.1-SNAPSHOT/scalala/generic/collection/CanSliceVector.html). The following isn't generic or necessarily efficient, but it works:

```
import scalala.generic.collection.CanSliceVector

implicit object svrSlicer extends
  CanSliceVector[SparseVectorRow[Double], Int, SparseVectorRow[Double]] {
  def apply(from: SparseVectorRow[Double], keys: Seq[Int]) =
    SparseVector.create(from.size)(keys.map(k => (k, from(k))): _*).t
}

val v: SparseVectorRow[Double] = SparseVector.create(10)((0, 1.0), (3, 2.0)).t
val v2: SparseVectorRow[Double] = v(List(1, 3, 5))
```

You could poke around in the Scalala source to figure out the "right" way to do this.